# Some cells won't show

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a chat applications with tableview to show the messages. Everything works fine except that some cells just won't show. It aren't always the same cells. I'm getting the messages from my Firebase database.

My Code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = cellCache.object(forKey: indexPath as AnyObject) as? UITableViewCell{
        return cell
    }

    let cell = messagesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherMessageCell") as! OtherMessageTableViewCell

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

        let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        if(uid == message.sender) {
            cell.sender.textAlignment = .right
            cell.message.textAlignment = .right
        }else{
            cell.sender.textAlignment = .left
            cell.message.textAlignment = .left
        }

        let uidReference = ref.child("Users").child(message.sender!)

        uidReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let username = dictionary["Username"] as! String
                let imageLink = dictionary["Image Link"] as! String

                cell.sender.text = username
                cell.message.text = message.message
                cell.profileImage.image = nil
                cell.profileImage.loadImageWithURLString(urlString: imageLink)
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.cellCache.setObject(cell, forKey: indexPath as AnyObject)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Example:
[image]

I hope someone will be able to help me. Thanks

Comment: Your code is actively fighting (and probably breaking) the framework. Both DispatchQueue calls and this `cellCache` thingamabob are unnecessary cruft that interfere with proper cell reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
var savedSenders = [Int: String]()
var savedMessages = [Int: String]()
var savedImages = [Int: UIImage]()
var savedAlignments = [Int: NSTextAlignment]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = messagesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherMessageCell") as! OtherMessageTableViewCell

    if(savedSenders[indexPath.row] != nil && savedMessages[indexPath.row] != nil && savedImages[indexPath.row] != nil && savedAlignments[indexPath.row] != nil) {
        cell.sender.textAlignment = savedAlignments[indexPath.row]!
        cell.message.textAlignment = savedAlignments[indexPath.row]!

        cell.sender.text = savedSenders[indexPath.row]
        cell.message.text = savedMessages[indexPath.row]
        cell.profileImage.image = savedImages[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    cell.sender.text = ""
    cell.message.text = ""
    cell.profileImage.image = nil

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

        let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        if(uid == message.sender) {
            cell.sender.textAlignment = .right
            cell.message.textAlignment = .right
            self.savedAlignments.updateValue(.right, forKey: indexPath.row)
        }else{
            cell.sender.textAlignment = .left
            cell.message.textAlignment = .left
            self.savedAlignments.updateValue(.left, forKey: indexPath.row)
        }

        let uidReference = ref.child("Users").child(message.sender!)

        uidReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let username = dictionary["Username"] as! String
                let imageLink = dictionary["Image Link"] as! String

                cell.sender.text = username
                cell.message.text = message.message
                cell.profileImage.image = nil
                cell.profileImage.loadImageWithURLString(urlString: imageLink)

                    let url = URL(string: imageLink)
                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

                        if(error != nil){
                            print(error as Any)
                            return
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                                let image = downloadedImage

                                self.savedSenders.updateValue(username, forKey: indexPath.row)
                                self.savedMessages.updateValue(message.message!, forKey: indexPath.row)
                                self.savedImages.updateValue(image, forKey: indexPath.row)
                            }
                        }
                    }.resume()
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    return cell
}
```

The data for every cell is saved into the arrays (savedSenders, savedMessages, savedImages and savedAlignments). If I don't save it into arrays, the cells will have to load all the data from Firebase and this will take longer. If it takes longer, it won't look good.
I tested everything and it works.